# Omniauth Strategy Outside Devise

Tags: ruby, oauth, devise

I've setup devise + omniauth for Google sign in. It works great on the web. I'm now looking at integrating the oauth sign in to iOS / Android clients.

I've been following https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/backend-auth and found that the library I'm using for oauth does these things (https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/google_oauth2.rb).

What I'm not clear about is if I can use a omniauth strategy outside the regular web workflow (i.e. from `rails console`) to build a pseudo `request.env["omniauth.auth"]`. Is something like that possible? Per the documentation https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/backend-auth#using-a-google-api-client-library I'd like to do the equivalent in Ruby (and am unclear if I can use Devise directly to do this).

Comment: You would have to provide some code, some kind of example of what you have tried so far, or a more thorough explanation of what you're trying to achieve. Can you make a pseudo `request` object? Sure, just make a struct. But whether you can accomplish anything with it or not depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: @anothermh I've added some more details

Answer (score -1):

Simulating requests in the console is pretty easy. You can easily make requests to the `app` variable the console provides:

```
app.get('/') # => 200
app.response # => #<ActionDispatch::TestResponse:0x007fc73e4db220>
```

As for handling authentication, standard rails applications use cookie/session-based authentication strategies on the web. After you authenticate the first time, some information gets stored in session (often as a cookie) that you and the server will pass back and forth with each request.

Since mobile clients don't rely on cookies, we need a different authentication strategy: [token-based authentication](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-ins-and-outs-of-token-based-authentication).

Here a high-level implementation that would work with Omniauth:

1. User Requests Access through Omniauth proivder by making requests to the Omniauth endpoint
2. Application processes the credentials
3. Application provides a signed token to the client
4. Client stores that token and sends it along with every request
5. Server verifies token and responds with data

For handling mobile requests, you'll need to be careful to follow the fine print for the provider's [Omniauth gem](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2#note-about-mobile-clients-ios-android).

Token authentication used to be baked into Devise, but it was removed. Thankfully, there are a few gems that add token auth to Devise:

- [simple_token_authentication](https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication)
- [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth)